# After a day grails program hangs. Need solution

Tags: mysql, email, grails, asynchronous

Here is the log. Problem occurse after a day with no interaction whatsoever. Is it the asynchronous mail plugin? is it a setting? Who can help me with this, any help is appreciated.

Grails 2.4.0, ubuntu 16.04

```
The last packet successfully received from the server was 278.019 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 218.021 milliseconds ago.
ERROR 2017-01-19 10:37:47,642 interceptor.TransactionInterceptor Application exception overridden by rollback exception
org.springframework.dao.RecoverableDataAccessException: Hibernate operation: could not prepare statement; SQL [update async_mail_mess set status=? where end_date<? and (status=? or status=?)]; Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 278.019 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 218.021 milliseconds ago.; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 278.019 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 218.021 milliseconds ago.
    at grails.plugin.asyncmail.AsynchronousMailPersistenceService$_updateExpiredMessages_closure4.doCall(AsynchronousMailPersistenceService.groovy:66)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withTransaction(GormStaticApi.groovy:814)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withTransaction(GormStaticApi.groovy:714)
    at grails.plugin.asyncmail.AsynchronousMailPersistenceService.updateExpiredMessages(AsynchronousMailPersistenceService.groovy:63)
    at grails.plugin.asyncmail.ExpiredMessagesCollectorJob.execute(ExpiredMessagesCollectorJob.groovy:13)
    at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:104)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 278.019 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 218.021 milliseconds ago.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3853)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2471)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2671)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:5024)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3834)
    ... 12 more
ERROR 2017-01-19 10:37:47,642 listeners.ExceptionPrinterJobListener Exception occurred in job: Grails Job
org.quartz.JobExecutionException: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: rollback failed [See nested exception: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: rollback failed]
    at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:111)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: rollback failed
    at grails.plugin.asyncmail.ExpiredMessagesCollectorJob.execute(ExpiredMessagesCollectorJob.groovy:13)
    at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:104)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: rollback failed
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to rollback against JDBC connection
    ... 4 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure during rollback(). Transaction resolution unknown.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:4757)
    ... 4 more
ERROR 2017-01-19 10:38:09,620 spi.SqlExceptionHelper Communications link failure
```

Comment: below answers maybe a little hasty.. AsynchronousMailPersistenceService$_updateExpiredMessages_closure4.doCall(AsynchronousMailPersistenceService.groovy:66) it starts here. It may be some record that has changed state or a configuration issue with the plugin - or what ever else - to put you right it relates to a plugin calles AsynchronousMail running on your grails application. Not specifically your grails application with the issue. Instead what runs inside it

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of two reasons

1.) your grails box got disconnected from the network.

2.) Your database server stops.

Answer (score 0):

You can add configuration parameters to your dataSource config to ensure the DB connection is kept alive

```
dataSource {
    properties {
        validationQuery=SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
        validationQueryTimeout=3
        validationInterval=15000
    }
}
```

The validationQuery will depend on your database vendor e.g. the above works with Oracle